# Why do Haskell list comprehensions with multiple generators treat the rightmost generator as the tightest loop?

Tags: haskell, conventions

I'm reading through the [Gentle Introduction](http://haskell.org/tutorial) and am wondering why in a list comprehension with two generators, the rightmost generator is iterated "the fastest" (i.e. compiles to the innermost loop, I guess). Observe the following GHCi output:

```hs
*Main> concat [[(x,y) | x <- [0..2]] | y <- [0..2]]
[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)]
*Main> [(x,y) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2]]
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

If the leftmost generator were iterated fastest, the above two expressions would have the same value, which I think makes choosing this convention more natural somehow.

So does anyone know why the opposite convention was chosen? I notice Python has the same convention as Haskell (maybe even borrowed it from Haskell?), and in Python world [the word](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) seems to be that the ordering was chosen "because that's the order in which you'd write a for loop", but I gather that thinking in terms of for loops is not exactly what most Haskell programmers do...

Thoughts?

---

From my comment on Louis Wasserman's answer below:

> I guess here the order corresponding to an imperative-style explication of the comprehension was considered more natural than having it correspond with nesting the list. So in essence the Haskell explanation for this is the same as the Python explanation I linked in the question, after all, it seems.

Comment: How would this be *more natural*? Do you also want 11, 21, 31, 41 instead of 11, 12, 13, 14?

Comment: I guess using `(y,x)` as the prototypical expression -- or putting the y generator to the left of the x generator -- would make more sense if the leftmost generator were the tightest loop. Then it would be the second line in my GHCi output which looked weird to you (11, 21, 31, 41), rather than the first, but they'd still be different from each other, which is my point.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should address you when replying to you, @Ingo. (Kind of new to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: I don't think there's a deep, technical reason, so if you're looking for something more than "because it felt right to the guys and gals making the language", well, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, so I gather from people's answers...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So that things scope in a sane way.

```
[(x, y) | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..x]]
```

makes sense -- `x` is in scope for the comprehension on `y` -- but

```
[(x, y) | y <- [1..x], x <- [1..10]]
```

makes somewhat less sense.

Additionally, this way it's consistent with the `do` monad syntax:

```
do x <- [1..10]
   y <- [1..x]
   return (x, y)
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to show how the same code would look using `do` monad syntax, for the uninitiated.

Comment: Hmm. As a beginner, I really don't see how the scoping is any less arbitrary than the order of generators. Again using my nesting example, `[[(x, y) | x <- [1..10]] | y <- [1..x]]` doesn't make sense, while `[[(x, y) | y <- [1..x]] | x <- [1..10]]` makes sense.

Comment: Nesting is (and is meant to be) totally different from the chained comprehension syntax.  In any event, the `do` notation has an unambigous order that the list comprehensions agree with.

Comment: Responding to your edit to add monad syntax (which indeed as @dflemstr guessed I am not yet familiar with :) ), that is not the same order, since the `return (x, y)` has moved to the end! But I see your point. I guess here the order corresponding to an imperative-style explication of the comprehension was considered more natural than having it correspond with nesting the list.

So in essence the Haskell explanation for this is the same as the Python explanation I linked in the question, after all, it seems.

Answer (score 7):

It may make more sense if you expand the list comprehension first into `do` notation and then into monadic binds. Let's say we want to write a comprehension where we refer back to names that are already bound:

```
[ (x,y) | x <- [1,2,3], y <- [x+1,x+2] ]
```

This expands to

```
do x <- [1,2,3]
   y <- [x+1,x+2]
   return (x,y)
```

which expands to

```
[1,2,3] >>= \x ->
[x+1,x+2] >>= \y -> 
return (x,y)
```

which makes it clear that `x` is in scope exactly when it needs to be.

If the expansion into `do` notation happened right-to-left instead of left-to-right, then our original expression would expand into

```
[x+1,x+2] >>= \y ->
[1,2,3] >>= \x ->
return (x,y)
```

which is clearly nonsensical - it refers to the value of `x` in a scope where `x` is not yet bound. So we'd have to write our original comprehension as

```
[ (x,y) | y <- [x+1,x+2], x <- [1,2,3] ]
```

to get the result we wanted, which seems unnatural - at the time your eye scans over the phrase `y <- [x+1,x+2]` you don't actually know what `x` is. You'd have to read the comprehension backwards to find out.

So it'd didn't *need* to be the case that the right-most binding is unrolled into the "inner loop" but it makes sense when you consider that humans are going to have to read the resulting code.

Comment: Yes, you make similar points to Louis Wasserman's answer, I think. But if the reasoning is really aligned with scoping order being left-to-right to fit with (English-speaking) humans reading from left to right, then why is the expression (`(x,y)`) on the left of the quantifications of its variables? Really, why not just follow the monadic order of instructions all the way, so that `[1,2,3] >>= \x -> [x+1,x+2] >>= \y -> return (x,y)` was sugared as, say, `[x <- [1,2,3], y <- [x+1,x+2] | (x,y)]`?

Comment: To put it another way, true, when you scan `y <- [x+1,x+2]`, you don't actually know what `x` is, but when you scan `(x,y)`, you don't know what either of `x` or `y` are, either.

Comment: That's a valid point. I suspect the reason for writing it this way is that it parallels mathematical [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Parallels_in_programming_languages) (remember that Haskell has many influences from mathematics). In case it helps you out - I always read the vertical bar `|` as "where" (I used to read it as "such that" in the days when I considered myself more of a mathematician than a programmer...)

Comment: So basically I guess this syntax is displaying the age-old cognitive dissonance between the drawing of an `g` arrow followed by a `f` arrow on a blackboard and the subsequent naming of the diagram as "`f \circ g`"... Pick one and stick with it! Somehow as a mathematics student I always wished that we wrote `(x)f` instead of `f(x)` to resolve this problem. Now it's followed me to Haskell world as well! :P

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Python uses the same scope structure as Haskell for list comprehensions.

Compare your Haskell:

```
*Main> concat [[(x,y) | x <- [0..2]] | y <- [0..2]]
[(0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)]
*Main> [(x,y) | x <- [0..2], y <- [0..2]]
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

with this Python:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[[(x,y) for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]))
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
>>> [(x,y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
>>>
```

Comment: Oops, you already knew. Any way, I'll leave this here for comparison.

Comment: Er, yes, that is what I meant :) I'll edit my question for clarity.